# How to detect maximum USB current in Android?

Tags: android

The Ampere app manages to display "max. usb curr." on some devices (but not all). For example, with a Qualcomm Fast Charger, it shows 1800mA, and with a USB port on a PC, it shows 500mA.

Where is it getting this information? I don't see anything in BatteryManager for this value. Is it reading directly from some manufacturer-specific location?

Note that this isn't the amps that are currently being delivered, it is the current that could theoretically be delivered by the charger (even if it isn't).